# create a dockerfile to run python and groovy app

Tags: java, python, docker, groovy, java-8

I am working on a project which is using both python and groovy to scrape data from websites and do some engineering on that data.

I want to create a dockerfile which should have a python(3.6.5) as base image and java8 and groovy should be installed on it to run my code.

the dockerfile I have right now is working for all the python codes(image : FROM python:3.6.5) but failing for groovy script and I cant find a solution which I can use to install groovy in dockerfile.

is there anyone who has a dockerfile solving this part problem ?

##########docker file below#############

```
FROM python:3.6.5

RUN sh -c "ls /usr/local/lib"


RUN sh -c "cat /etc/*-release"

# Contents of requirements.txt each on a separate line for incremental builds
RUN pip install SQLAlchemy==1.2.7
RUN pip install pandas==0.23.0
RUN pip uninstall bson
RUN pip install pymongo
RUN pip install openpyxl==2.5.3
RUN pip install joblib
RUN pip install impyla


RUN sh -c "mkdir -p /src/dateng"

ADD . /src/dateng

RUN sh -c "ls /src/dateng"

WORKDIR /src/dateng/

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/src/dateng/_aws/trigger.py"]
```

Comment: You need to share your current Dockerfile so that we can help you.

Comment: dockerfile added, please check

Comment: Is it absolutely required that you have both the python and java code in the same container? One very complex container design will likely be harder to work with than two more basic containers that communicate with a simple REST API.

Alternatively, is there some reason that you have to use groovy/python when either language is likely capable of handling the job both parts of the work you are doing?

Comment: It could have been 2 different containers for python and groovy but then it would have required some complex synchronization. Thus I am avoiding that.

I agree with you that both languages are capable of handling both parts of the work, but I am just involved in moving this code to aws after dockerization as this was coded by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `sh -c command`, just `RUN command` and we should not use a RUN instruction per command, intead we should group them in only one `RUN`, because each `RUN` is a separated layer in the docker image, thus increasing the final size of it.

## Possible Solution

Inspired in [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/approov/python-flask_approov-shapes-demo-server/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile) I use for a Python demo:

```
FROM python:3.6.5

ARG CONTAINER_USER="python"
ARG CONTAINER_UID="1000"

# Will not prompt for questions
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    CONTAINER_USER=python \
    CONTAINER_UID=1000

RUN apt update && \
    apt -y upgrade && \
    apt -y install \
      ca-certificates \
      locales \
      tzdata \
      inotify-tools \
      python3-pip \
      groovy && \

    locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8 && \
    dpkg-reconfigure locales && \

    #https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers
    printf "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288\n" >> /etc/sysctl.conf && \

    useradd -m -u ${CONTAINER_UID} -s /bin/bash ${CONTAINER_USER}

ENV LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=en_GB:en \
    LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8

USER ${CONTAINER_USER}

RUN pip3 install \
      fSQLAlchemy==1.2.7 \
      pandas==0.23.0 \
      pymongo \
      openpyxl==2.5.3 \
      joblib \
      impyla && \
    pip3 uninstall bson


# pip install will put the executables under ~/.local/bin
ENV PATH=/home/"${CONTAINER_USER}"/.local/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /home/${CONTAINER_USER}/workspace

ADD . /home/${CONTAINER_USER}/dataeng

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/home/python/dateng/_aws/trigger.py"]
```

> **NOTE**: I am behind a corporate firewall, therefore I cannot test building this image as it is now, because I would need to add stuff to it that you don't need. Let me know if something doesn't work for you and I will work it out from home.

Comment: this answer worked like a charm only after removing this line "USER ${CONTAINER_USER}" as after changing the user there were some permission issues while installing packages sqlalchemy, pandas etc.

I have marked this answer as accepted. thanks

Comment: The line you removed is necessary to not run your app as root, because that is a bad practice and a security risk. I will try to debug this later on when I am in home... at work I am behind a corporate Firewall. What is the Operating System  of your computer?

Comment: this python:3.6.5 takes debian as base image, so I am running this in docker.
OS of my computer is Windows 10